# ngx-contextmenu - this.overlay.position(...) connectedTo is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular13, ngx-contextmenu

I am using **ngx-contextmenu 5.4.0** and recently upgraded **angular version to 13**.

After upgrade context menu was not visible and was throwing following error.

[image: Overlay error]

I tried changing version of **@angular/cdk to 11.2.13** and **it worked**.

But I have some other features which requires @angular/cdk 13.1.1.
I even tried another combination @angular/cdk 13.1.1 and ngx-contextmenu 6.0.0,
but even that didn't work.

How do I go about?

Comment: Well just look to the documentation. In Angular CDK v11, `connectedTo` is marked as deprecated. In v13 it was removed. https://v11.material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayPositionBuilder

Comment: Also, the package you mention has an open issue with that exact problem you describe. https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu/issues/242

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is an open GitHub issue which describes this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't wanna read the github discussion:
just remove the ngx-contextmenu and then add the @perfectmemory/ngx-contextmenu with npm, 7.0.0 for angular 13, and 6.0.0 for angular 12, it's the same but one user fixed the bug

but just in case, i'll leave you here the link to the issue discussion:
https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu/issues/242